# React - Access or assign data object directly to Field component for FieldArray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I am having some concept problem in using **FieldArray**, I have multiple Select components wired to **FieldArray**, each select component should update value **onChange** and should delete it **through api**. To be able to perform api request I need to access other details for the field like **id**. I have setup my component something like shown below, it works fine without api call..

```
renderAdditionalSpeakers({fields}){
    return (<div>
      {
        fields.map((speaker,index)=>
          <Field
            name={`${speaker}.speakerid`}
            label="Choose Speaker"
            type="select"
            component={this.renderSelectWithDelete}
            mandatory='false'
            placeholder='Select Speaker'
            opts={this.props.speakers}
            key={`KEY-${index}`}
            deleteaction={() => fields.remove(index)}
            onChange={this.onSpeakerChange.bind(this)}
        />
      )
    }
    <div className="form-group row">
      <div className="col-sm-3">&nbsp;</div>
      <div className="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-0">
        <Button className="button-theme button-theme-blue" type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Link More Speaker</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>);
  }
```

and render method look like this

```
render() {

    var {handleSubmit, invalid, pristine, submitting,speakers,tracks} = this.props;

    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <FieldArray name="additionalspeakers" component={this.renderAdditionalSpeakers.bind(this)}/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}
```

From the above code, I need to call api with in **ondeleteaction** callback and **onChange** action. This is only possible when I can access the json object which consist of following values

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "speakerid":"23",
   "sessionid":"102",
   "eventid":"200"
}
```

How to achieve?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass further arguments to your field array and use them within your render method, like

```
<FieldArray name="additionalspeakers" component={this.renderAdditionalSpeakers.bind(this)} props={{ onDeleteAction: this.ondeleteaction, onChange: this.onChange }} />
```

(where `this.ondeleteaction` and `this.onChange` are the callback function defined in your component).

Then you can declare the FieldArray as:

```
renderAdditionalSpeakers({fields, onDeleteAction, onChange}) {
```

and use the function callbacks within the component.